# Кодирование с помощью RSA

Tags: java, rsa

Во время написания лабораторной столкнулся с проблемой. В Джаве для написания алгоритмы шифрования и дешифрования RSA использовать либу Security нельзя, пришлось писать на том, что имеем.

Дело в том, что во время кодирования у меня все символы при декодировании никак не попадают в диапазон латинских символов, какие бы значения не вводились, коды символов всегда больше тысячи, либо меньше нуля. Алгоритмы вроде верны, подсчёты тоже производятся правильно, но никак не могу понять в чём проблема.

Попытки переписать функцию быстрого возведения в степень ни к чему не привели (его нужно использовать по условию задания, как и расширенный алгоритм Евклида).

Знаю, что в Джаве по умолчанию используется UTF-8, но сильно мне это не помогло.

Код прикрепляю:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

//функция быстрого возведения в степень
//Пусть m=(mkmk−1...m1m0)2 — двоичное представление степени n
//Тогда n=mk⋅2k+mk−1⋅2k−1+...+m1⋅2+m0, где mk=1,mi∈{0,1} и xn=x^((...((mk⋅2+mk−1)⋅2+mk−2)⋅2+...)⋅2+m1)⋅2+m0
public static int fastPower(int val1, int val2, int n) {

    if (val2 == 1)
        return 1;

    int tmp = fastPower(val1, val2 / 2, n);

    if (val2 % 2 == 0)
        return (tmp * tmp) % n;
    else
        return (val1 * tmp * tmp) % n;
}

//расширенный алгоритм Евклида для вычисления НОД
//умножение чисел всегда быстрее, чем разложение результата на простые множители
public static int[] GCDex(int a, int b) {
    int aTemp = a;
    int bTemp = b;
    int s1 = 1, s2 = 0;
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1;
    int[] toReturn = new int[3];
    int quotient = 0;

    while (bTemp != 0){
        quotient = aTemp / bTemp;
        int temp = aTemp % bTemp;
        aTemp = bTemp;
        bTemp = temp;
        int tempS = s1 - s2 * quotient;
        s1 = s2;
        s2 = tempS;
        int tempR = t1 - t2 * quotient;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = tempR;
    }

    toReturn[0] = aTemp;
    toReturn[1] = s1;
    toReturn[2] = t1;

    return toReturn;
}


public static int fi(int p, int q) {
    return (p - 1) * (q - 1);
}

public static int GCD (int val1, int val2){
    while (val2 != 0){
        int temp = val1 % val2;
        val1 = val2;
        val2 = temp;
    }
    return val1;
}

public static int[] generateOpenKey(int p, int q, int rangeMax) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int n = p * q;
    int nEyler = fi(p, q);
    int e;
    do {
        e = random.nextInt(nEyler);
    } while ((GCD(nEyler, e) != 1) || (e <= 1));

    int[] toReturn = new int[2];
    toReturn[0] = e;
    toReturn[1] = n;
    System.out.println("Open key is: <" + toReturn[0] + ", " + toReturn[1] + ">");
    return toReturn;
}

public static ArrayList<String> encryptWithRSA(String toEncrypt, int e, int n){
    ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.length(); i++){
        int index = toEncrypt.charAt(i);
        int result = fastPower(index, e, n);
        toReturn.add(String.valueOf(result));
    }

    return toReturn;
}

public static String decryptWithRSA(ArrayList<String> input, int d, int n){
    String toReturn = "";

    for (String character : input){
        int c = Integer.parseInt(character);
        int index = fastPower(c, d, n);
        toReturn = toReturn.concat(String.valueOf((char) index));
    }

    return toReturn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scannerString = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scannerInt = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input you string to encrypt: ");

    String toEncrypt = scannerString.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Input p: ");
    int p = scannerInt.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Input q: ");
    int q = scannerInt.nextInt();

    int[] openKey;
    //contains e, n and fi(n)
    openKey = generateOpenKey(p, q,100);

    int fiN = fi(p, q);

    //contains d-exponent value
    int[] secretKey = GCDex(fiN, openKey[0]);
    int d = secretKey[2];
    if (d < 0){
        d += fiN;
    }

    ArrayList<String> encrypted = encryptWithRSA(toEncrypt, openKey[0], openKey[1]);
    System.out.print("Encrypted: ");
    System.out.println(encrypted.toString());

    System.out.print("Decrypted: ");
    System.out.println(decryptWithRSA(encrypted, d, openKey[1]));
  }
}
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Я не понял. Проблема в том, что при декодировании вы получаете не то, что закодировали? Чтоб исключить проблему в конвертации в строки, попробуйте кодировать просто массив байт. Это работает как нужно?